# How to restore built in procedure in Scheme (Racket SICP)

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am using Racket (DrRacket) with SICP package.

So, I am redefining built-in procedure `` like this:

```
#lang sicp
(define + 6)
```

**Question:** How to restore built-in procedure `+` to its original state?

Comment: (define orig+ +) (define + 6) orig+

Comment: If you want the original procedure, just don't define something with the same name. It's not very useful to redefine built-ins like this.

Comment: comment out that line of code and reload the file (by clicking "Run" at the top, or pressing `Ctrl-R`).